# Get the internal hidden states of an LSTM in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have an LSTM with N hidden units, and when I'm using pytorch's `nn.LSTM` I get the output of all of the units, but the hidden and cell state of only the last unit. I want to also use the intermediate hidden states of the intermediate hidden units, what's the simplest way of doing that?

Comment: How many layers do you have? Are you putting a dense layer on top of LSTM(s) and reading its output? Can you show us some simple code as to what you get and what you'd like to get? Is [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) of LSTM helpful?

Comment: One layer only. No dense layers. It's a conceptual question so no code is necessary. The documentation says that c_n is "containing the cell state for t = seq_len.", and doesn't explain how to get the cell state also for t<seq_len. same for h_n (which in the meanwhile I understood I can get from "output" which is half a solution actually).

Comment: For the cell states: there is currently [no way](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/31423) to retrieve those with `nn.LSTM`. You may want to roll your own LSTM with `nn.LSTMCell`s or see some attempts in the github issue linked.